# Can't Stringify the Object that Contains DOM Elements on it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an object that has an key on it and its value is html content from the dom. (I will try to send this in Back latter). But I can't do that for some reasons.

Here is how I build it.

```js
const handlePrintOrder = () => {
    const html = document.getElementById('invoice'); // this takes the elements
    const body = {content: html}; // here I build the object
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body)) // this gives an error
  };
```

And here is the error:

```sh
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLElement'
    |     property '__reactFiber$8di0naxlmzf' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle
```

I don't know if you need this but here is my dom (simpliefied, but is dynamic):

```
<section id='invoice'>
      <div class='box'>
        <hr class='linebreak' />
        <div class='box_wrappers'>
          <div style={{ marginRight: '8em' }}>
            <div class='information-wrapper'>
              <p class='information-item-title'>MARKE:</p>
              {/* <p class='infromation-item-item'>${order.vehicle.brand}</p> */}
            </div>
            <div class='information-wrapper'>
              <p class='information-item-title'>MODELL:</p>
              {/* <p class='infromation-item-item'>${order.vehicle.model}</p> */}
            </div>

            <div class='information-wrapper'>
              <p class='information-item-title'>TERMIN:</p>
              {/* <p class='infromation-item-item'>${order.appointment}</p> */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML` to get the HTML content.

Comment: @Barmar, the `innerHTML` will only provide the HTML inside the `#invoice` element. It won't provide HTML attributes of `invoice` element. Hence `outerHTML` attribute should be used.

Comment: @Ashok Whether to use `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` depends on how the JSON will eventually be used.

Comment: @Barmar, agreed :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stringify an HTMLElement, since it contains the references to the parent Element. Since both parent and child contains each other's references, you get a circular dependency, which cannot be stringify.

To fix this you can use something like `HTMLElement.outerHTML` to get stringified version of HTMLElement.

So your code would be as follow:

```js
const handlePrintOrder = () => {
    const html = document.getElementById('invoice'); // this takes the elements
    const body = {content: html.outerHTML }; // here I build the object
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body)) // this gives an error
  };
```

Comment: Yes it worked but on the server, is not receiving as object what we should do?

Comment: @cutrimafyi you won't be able to send HTML Element as object to the server instead we can just send the string data. But, we can restore the HTML string to HTML objects by using `HTMLElement.innerHTML` like `div.innerHTML = response.content`